# SlickGrid - Background Loading of Pages

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

The lazy loading functionality is very cool in SlickGrid - but has anyone had any experience of the background loading of future pages?

This would therefore mean that there is no buffering/loading of data when a user gets to a point of the grid where there is no data yet loaded - therefore speeding up the user experience.

Comment: Are you referring to the lazy-loading of DOM elements or data (via ajax)?

Comment: @Tin - the lazy loading of the data - this is working fine but we just want to load it async so that the user doesn't encounter any white space when scrolling down.

Comment: So you want to load the grid with the initial page-worth of data and then start downloading the rest in the background?  Have you considered the additional load on the server this would cause?  Perhaps some sort of predictive Ajax loading would work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a workaround for this by using setTimeout, so every time we go to get 50 records, we are setting a timeout to get another 50 in a few seconds.

Comment: That's a nice idea but how does it look in code? I'd like to do something similar for lazy loading JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to offer this kind of functionality.

**Prefetching.**
[Mozilla: Link Prefetching FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/link_prefetching_faq)

Adding the following to the `head` of **page1.htm** would allow background prefetching of **page2.htm** in browsers supporting this functionality.

```
<link rel="next" href="page2.htm" >
```

As I said, I am not sure of the browsers which do, and do not, support this functionality, but, if you were wanting to provide the same functionality for all browsers, you could also code, in jQuery, a function which runs for any browsers which do not support the Prefetch, to create a hidden iFrame.

**IFrames**
[StackOverflow: iframe preloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478184/is-using-iframes-to-improve-page-performance-an-acceptable-approach)

Creating an iframe, like the following, either through basic HTML coding, or dynamically using jQuery, would load **page2.htm** whilst still displaying **page1.htm** (and should provide a performance boost so long as the referenced page is cache-friendly).

```
<iframe src="page2.htm" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="position:absolute;top:-3000px;left:-3000px;></iframe>
```